# Jenkins/Robot Framework - looking for chromedriver but I think it's in PATH

Tags: jenkins, path, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Hey in Jenkins I'm trying to run robot framework tests:
with command `python3 robot -d results mytestsuite.robot`, and it has some line to open chrome browser, but the message in log shows me typical: `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see...`

Everything works ok locally, and I'm not sure which PATH jenkins wants to use so my questions are:

1. why do I have to input python3 instead of python (with just python in command it tells me that robot is not found)
2. why chromedriver is not found, and how to set it up (in what PATH and how) to make it work
3. Is it possible to set jenkins up to use other drivers ex. geckodriver?

My jenkins job env looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $JENKINS_HOME
which python3
echo $PATH
```

outputs:

```
/Users/MYUSER/.jenkins
/usr/bin/python3
/Users/MYUSER/.jenkins/tools/chromedriver:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've fixed it with:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/:$PATH
```

this is the location where I have chromedriver locally.

in the build shell execute but is there a way to make it more permanent (I mean not to use it every time it runs build?)

Comment: you could use webdrivermanager and install chromedriver with it, it has functionality to place the chromedriver into PATH if it finds a writeable directory. as a benefit, latest release adds auto probing of of chrome version and downloading correct version: https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/ .. disclaimer, i maintain that project.